# How to compute and pass array in props?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-props

I'm using [react-form](https://react-form.js.org) to make a simple form and want to pass in a list of items to the `Select` Component. The `Select` Component is a part of the `react-form` library.

I want to pass a `fooItems` to the `Select`

Required Structure for `Select` Component

```
selectItems = [{
  value: 1,
  label: 'a',
}, {
  value: 2,
  label: 'b',
}]
```

I first want to filter my `fooItems` array recieved from Redux `mapStateToProps`

```
fooItems = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'a',
  parent: 'P',
  child: 'C'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'b',
  parent: 'P',
  child: 'C'
}]
```

I'm trying to implement a function while passing the props in to the Component

```js
render() => (
    <Select
    field = "foo"
    id = "foo"
    options = {
      () => {
        return this.props.fooItems.map(e => {
          return {
            label: e.name,
            value: e.id
          }
        })
      }
    }
    />)
```

But I get the following Errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
at t.value (index.js:1)

The above error occurred in the <t> component:
in t (created by r)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Options` field requires an array of object, however you are passing it a function. You either need to call that function

```
render() => (
    <Select
    field = "foo"
    id = "foo"
    options = {
      () => {
        return this.props.fooItems.map(e => {
          return {
            label: e.name,
            value: e.id
          }
        })
      }();
    }
 />)
```

or you should directly return the result of map

```
render() => (
    <Select
    field = "foo"
    id = "foo"
    options = {this.props.fooItems.map(e => {
          return {
            label: e.name,
            value: e.id
          }
        })
    }
 />)
```